# Settings for importing custom java classes from other project in clojure, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure, classnotfoundexception

I want to import java classes from a java project into a clojure project.

I have tried the following, with no success:

- convert the java project into a jar file. then added it as external jar library to the clojure project.
- adding the java project to the build path of the clojure project

The code I used was

```
(ns clojuretest.core
(:import [packagename classname]))
```

All of these give ClassNotFoundException

Edit: I also tried to import a class by accessing a source .java file I created inside the clojure project. I made a source folder "java/src" and then added  `:java-source-paths ["java/src"]`
in the project.clj. This resulted in

> Java compiler not found; Be sure to use java from a JDK rather than a
>   JRE by modifying PATH or setting JAVA_CMD.

Comment: You need to create a Clojure Run/Debug configuration otherwise it's leiningen which manages the classpath.

Comment: if you mean Run as-> run configurations, that resulted in a NullpointerException.

Comment: `Run`> `Run Configurations...`, then select `Clojure` in the list and click on `New Configuration`

Comment: yes as i said above it returns an error when i do this. first it was NullpointerException, now it seems to pop up a window saying "internal error in launching"